# Combining View and Viewset Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer for  **StacItem** and a simple viewset for it say

```
class StacItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

class StacItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StacItemSerializer
    queryset = StacItems.objects.all()
```

I also created a custom view

```
class StacItemMainView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        items = {}
        items['type'] = "Example"
        
        return Response(items)
```

In my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'items', StacItemMainView.as_view()),
]

router.register(r'items/<id>', StacItemViewSet, basename='item')


urlpatterns += router.urls
```

What I want to achieve is to have an endpoint to `apps/items/` using the APIView and on the same time I want the endpoint for each *Item* i.e. `apps/items/{id}` from the viewset using the serializer. How can I customize the urls to point it correctly?

Comment: You've used viewsets.ModelViewSet which also includes the ListModelMixin. Do you want it to not be used?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `<id>` in the router.register (and it won't actually be parsed). The router will generate the detail URLs automatically from the ViewSet. If the following doesn't work, try to use `GenericViewSet` + all mixins except `ListModelMixin` mixin, instead of the `ModelViewSet`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'items', StacItemMainView.as_view()),
]
router.register('items', StacItemViewSet, basename='item')
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: Hi, I added all the Mixins except the ListModelMixin but it did not work.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Also, @Mark Rofail is right, you'd better use the single ViewSet and override the `list` method if you want separate logic for it

Answer (score 1):

`ModelViewset` already includes `RetreiveMixin` if you just want to use a different serializer for the detail view override `get_serializer` and if condition on `self.action == retreive`

For example, I prefer doing something like

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_classes = {
        "retreive": RetreiveSerializer,
        "default": DefaultSerializer
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.serializer_classes["default"])
```

Comment: I do not understand. Can you give an example code?